# Cannot Open Metadata file iostream in C++

Tags: error-handling, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and when I started my preprocessor directive

```
 #using <iostream>
```

I get an error message saying "Error: cannot open metadata file "iostream". Anyone know what might be causing this issue? Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++, you want `#include <iostream>` instead of `#using <iostream>`.  #Using is a c# thing for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

You typed `iosteam` instead of `iostream`